# Getting path of csv file from where data is being loaded in SQL loader.

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-loader

I am trying to import data into a table in Oracle from a CSV file using SQL Loader. However, I want to add two additional attributes namely date of upload and the file path from which the data is being imported. I can add the date using SYSDATE, Is there a similar method of obtaining the file path?

Comment: Are you calling the sql-loader executable via command line ?

Comment: Yes, I am Sudipta.

Comment: I don't think there is any way, the only option is to create a control file on the fly. Have a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552947/use-parameters-with-ctl

Comment: This is a complete example - http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/12234/35341/#msg_35341

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with using SYSDATE is that it will not be the same for all rows.  This can make it difficult if you do more than one load in a day and need to back out a particular load.  Consider using a batch_id also using the method in this post: [Insert rows with batch id using sqlldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602392/insert-rows-with-batch-id-using-sqlldr/50701476#50701476)
I suspect it could be adapted to use the SYSDATE as well so it would be the same for all rows.  Give it a try and let us know.  At any rate, using a batch_id from a sequence would make working with problems much easier should you need to delete based on a batch_id.